# Git-Tfs missing history on branch

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, git-tfs

I am migrating to from TFS to Git and using Git-tfs. I have managed to download the source code from the TFS Server for all branches.

The main branch ($/Project/Main) is fine and works but one of the branch (fs) that was created off the main does not have all the check-ins. I did try a git-tfs pull but no luck.

The problem branch has this history.

- c180 - Branched from $/Project/A
- c181 - Deleted the branch
- c182 - Branched from $/Project/Main

The branch fs only have up-to c180 - Branched from $/Project/A and nothing after this. The command I ran:

```
git tfs clone tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/Project/fs
```

Is there a way or a workaround to pull the rest of the commits on the branch fs.?

Please advise?

Comment: Can you add the related command to show what did you do?

Comment: git tfs clone http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/some_project

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT based on your own answer you posted **earlier** you know the history is nested inside the changeset for the branch in the gui only, it seems clear that he's asking how to retrieve that in his git history: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482439/create-new-tfs-branch-with-history/36495586#36495586

Answer (score -1):

Try running this command from the folder of "fs" branch:

```
git-tfs pull -c=181
```

Comment: All this command does for me is make a new commit for the exact same tfvc changeset labeled by that id.

Comment: OP also mentioned in his question he tried a git tfs pull already